# Search 2013 list crawled Properties per result

Tags: 2013, search, crawled-property

Is there a way to list all the crawled properties associated with a specific search result?

I know a particular item was crawled. It is listed in the crawl log. Before mapping managed properties, before doing anything else, is there any way to know which crawled properties are associated with that item? Is there a way through the UI, PowerShell or api? This is an on-prem instance

Comment: List the properties where? Do you mean programmatically?

Comment: code, powershell, ui, anyway?

Comment: How are you retrieving the Search Result?

Comment: I've edited the question for further clarity

Comment: That's much more clear, I don't have the answer for that on the top of my head, but hopefully someone in the Community wil be able to help anytime soon.

Answer (score 1):

If I read your question exactly, you want the available crawled properties for a search result. I don't think you can, but you can get the Managed Properties. Mikael wrote up the technique and it still works on perm and there is a workaround in the cloud: http://techmikael.blogspot.no/2014/03/debugging-managed-properties-using.html

Essentially there is a property that contains all properties: `managedproperties(filter=600/0/*)` that you can return in your search result.

The SharePoint 2013 Search Query Tool on CodePlex is great for exactly this purpose. Be sure to turn on the Experimental Features. https://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/

Comment: Hi Matthew. It's precisely to create managed properties that I can use in that same searchtool that I'm trying to find the crawled properties to map into :-)

Comment: That is a challenge, particularly AFTER you have done the crawl of new content. One trick I use is to set up a fresh test server and the capture all the crawled props in PowerShell, then run a crawl of sample content and run the script again looking at the delta. I have yet to find an elegant way of finding crawled props associated with an indexed item.

Comment: That is a good idea! I'll see if I can get my hands on a clean env. Thanks Matthew

Comment: I wrote this quite a while ago, should help: http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2011/09/28/troubleshooting-ifilters-and-crawled-properties/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Caml Query Builder. Connect to that list using that tool and fire a query. You will get list items, in header you will see column names for example: ows_Title. This ows_Title(and other column names listed as headers) will become crawled property after full crawl.

Comment: A link to the tool would be very helpful :)

Comment: http://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/ is the tool :)

Comment: Thanks Varun. In the case I'm looking at, CAML won't help me because the content is not in SharePoint. I'm looking at an external web site made in SiteCore. There will be meta tags exposed by the site, and there will be a number of crawled properties associated with the content type 'Web Page' that I'm hoping to map into managed properties. I'm just in the beginning of exploring what you can do with the Enterprise Search, but there doesn't seem to be a lot of documentation or even books. The only thing I can find are Mann's books, that seem very overpriced and  with very little technical depth

Comment: @JorgeCarvalho are you using BCS to get the data into SharePoint?